# Convergence of a Special Series as N is large

Tags: summation

I'm trying to find a general formula for the series and x is a constant:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N  \frac{i}{(1+r)^i}$$
I have deduced the general formula for the sum.
$$\frac{(1+r)^{N+1}-(1+r)-rN}{r^2(1+r)^N}$$
Will this sum converge to some value when N is very large? Could someone explain how to deal with it?

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30741/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got the general formula.